# Server 2003 won't let me rename the computer

Tags: windows-server-2003, rename, windows

I've got a windows server 2003 (standard edition) partition running as a non-domain computer.

I attempt to rename the computer and update the description using the My Computer -> Properties window, but after restarting the machine, a weird looking dialog pops up saying that the network identification has been changed and I need to restart the computer again for the changes to take effect.

[image]

If I check the My Computer -> Properties window again - the description is updated, but the computer name has reverted back to the old name!   No matter how many times I type in the new name and restart, it always reverts back and gives me the weird dialog.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not a standard Windows dialog. I think you'll find there's some 3rd party software that's causing your issue.

Comment: Blugh, I think you're right.  Curse you ASUS... and your crappy USB wireless driver.  Seriously wtf.....

Comment: @Farseeker - Yep, that was it.  If you want to put your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a standard Windows dialog. I think you'll find there's some 3rd party software that's causing your issue.

Comment: I had an Asus USB-N11 wireless USB adapter stuck in the machine.  When I first installed it, I made the mistake of installing their utility suite of software.  That's what was causing the issue.